# How to plot a vector from a starting point and following a specific direction in degrees in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to plot some vectors starting at a specific point 55 degrees north and 20 degrees east and follow a direction according to a random angle (generate with randn).
I thought about doing it with a loop but that did not work out :

```
for i=1:100
    a=50+ 20.*randn;
    b = [a];
    i = i + 1;
    route = [20,50] + b * 
    plot(route, 'color', 'magenta')
    hold on
end
```

»»»  route = [20,50] + b *   i tried it like this because for me it looks like a stupid linear equation of the type of y = a+ bx ... i just don't know what to use for x...
Also this way it will plot only 1 route and I need 100...

(So I need on one graph hundred vectors starting from the same point where the only parameter that varies is the direction)

Hope someone can help me. Any ideas?

ps: i am just starting matlab.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Try the following code for one line with direction:

```
%Initial line information
startPoint = [20 50] ;
direction  = [4 3] ;
lineLength = 100;

%Initialize line points with zeros
x  = zeros(lineLength);
y  = zeros(lineLength);

% Update line points
for i = 1 : lineLength
    x(i) = startPoint(1) + direction(1) * i;
    y(i) = startPoint(2) + direction(2) * i;
end

%Plot the line
plot( y , x ,'r.');
```

2 - And if you want the direction to be changing for every point,

use the following code:

```
%Initial line values
startPoint = [20 50] ;
lineLength = 100;

%create random direction vector
randomMax  = 100;
direction  = randi(randomMax,lineLength,2);

%Initialize line points with zeros
x  = zeros(lineLength);
y  = zeros(lineLength);

%set first points
x(1) = startPoint(1);
y(1) = startPoint(2);

% Update line points accumulating on previous point
for i = 2 : lineLength
    x(i) = x(i - 1) + direction(i,1) * i;
    y(i) = y(i - 1) + direction(i,2) * i;
end

%Plot the line
plot( y , x ,'r.');
```

3 - For various line each with different direction use the following code:

```
%Initial line values
startPoint = [20 50] ;
lineLength = 100;

%create random the 100 directions vector
randomMax  = 100;
directions = randi(randomMax,lineLength,2);

%Initialize line points with zeros
x  = zeros(lineLength,100);
y  = zeros(lineLength,100);

%set first points
x(1) = startPoint(1);
y(1) = startPoint(2);

h3 = figure;

% Update line points accumulating on previous point
for k = 1 : 100
    for i = 2 : lineLength

        x(i,k) = x(i - 1,k) + directions(k,1) * i;
        y(i,k) = y(i - 1,k) + directions(k,2) * i;

    end
    %hold the figure and plot the k-th line
    hold on;    
    plot( y(: , k) , x(: , k) , 'r.');
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the first part. But for the second part, it is not the direction in the line I want to change 100 times but the direction of the entire vector. I want to have 100 vectors with 100 different random directions on the same graph... But the linelength does not change. the length does not matter... And that's my problem for the next step !

Comment: Try the new third part of the answer for various lines each with different direction.